# Explanation of result for Double.valueOf

Tags: java, floating-point

I want to know the reason why i am getting so many decimal points while doing this sum of double numbers

```
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(".56"));
double dvalue=1.12+Double.parseDouble(".56");
System.out.println(dvalue);
```

output is as follows 
0.56 and 
1.6800000000000002 
why second summation is adding those decimals it  should simply  1.68

Comment: Take a look at Floating Point arithmetic on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: OK - this will be closed as a many time duplicate, I'm sure - but for the OP here is, in my opinion, the best link to explain this http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 4):

It's because the *addition* of the doubles 1.12 and 0.56 does not yield an exact representation of 1.68 (it doesn't precisely result in 1.68). You can see the difference with this code:

```
System.out.println(1.12+0.56);   // 1.6800000000000002
System.out.println(1.68);        // 1.68
```

Comment: It is true that 1.68 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point format, but this has nothing to do with what happens in the question. **Exactly one `double` floating-point number is printed by `System.out.println` as "1.68".** The question is why `1.12+Double.parseDouble(".56")` does not compute this `double`. The answer to that is that 1.12 is not represented exactly, that 0.56 is not represented exactly, and that `+` is not mathematical addition.

Comment: To illustrate how “1.68 cannot be represented exactly” is simply the wrong answer, one can imagine a different question in which the mathematical result of a sequence of operations would have been 4, and the operations interpreted as floating-point operations produce the result `0x1.0000000000001p2`. Would you say that the reason for this superficially surprising result is that 4 cannot be represented exactly as a `double`?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Your comments make perfect sense. The answer is now updated. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: As it happens, in this particular case, the addition gets the same answer as real number addition for the same inputs. The inputs are 1.12000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875 and 0.560000000000000053290705182007513940334320068359375, sum 1.680000000000000159872115546022541821002960205078125.